# How to flatMap while keeping hierarchy with original object

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
case class Rule(a: Int, expression: String, c: String)
val initialVar: Array[Rule] = Array(
  Rule(1, "#25.2.3 Sometext #528.55555.8", "Somename"),
  Rule(1, "#850.152.2.0 Sometext", "Somename")
)
```

I want to flatMap expression and get something like:

```
val finalVar: Array[(Rule, String)] = Array(
  (Rule(1, "#25.2.3 Sometext #528.55555.8", "Somename"),"25.2.3"),
  (Rule(1, "#25.2.3 Sometext #528.55555.8", "Somename"),"528.55555.8"),
  (Rule(1, "#850.152.2.0 Sometext", "Somename"),"850.152.2.0")
)
```

I could reproduce some flatMap examples but still can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? why are you discarding "Sometext" and keeping the numbers?

Comment: Sorry Giovanni, I should've been more specific: I wanted to flatmap whatever is after '#' while keeping the relation with the expression that generated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have function `expandRule` that maps your rule to `Seq[String]` of subexprs, your flatMap will look like this:

```
case class Rule(a: Int, expression: String, c: String)

val initialVar: Array[Rule] = Array(
  Rule(1, "#25.2.3 Sometext #528.55555.8", "Somename"),
  Rule(1, "#850.152.2.0 Sometext", "Somename")
)

def expandRule(r:Rule):Seq[String] = 
  "#[\\d.]+".r.findAllMatchIn(r.expression).map(_.group(0)).toSeq


initialVar.flatMap(r => expandRule(r).map(r -> _))
```

And this will give you:

```
res0: Array[(Rule, String)] = Array((Rule(1,#25.2.3 Sometext #528.55555.8,Somename),#25.2.3), (Rule(1,#25.2.3 Sometext #528.55555.8,Somename),#528.55555.8), (Rule(1,#850.152.2.0 Sometext,Somename),#850.152.2.0))
```